# .htaccess send index.html instead status 404

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use angular.js and slim framework for api. My directory structure is

```
root/
   api/
   frontend/
   .htaccess
```

In root directory I have `.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/frontend/$1 !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/frontend/$1 !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/frontend/$1 -d [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/frontend/$1 -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/frontend/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/$1 [L]
```

It work ok but when I try to get file that doesn't exists apache returns content of `index.html` and `status 200 OK` instead of `404` so code like this

```
<script src="/thisFileDoesntExists.js"></script>
```

will return content of `index.html`. How to retun `404` for wrong files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first rule is the culprit which is sending all non-files/directories to `index.html`. Remove it with a `DirectoryIndex` on top:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/frontend/$1 -d [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/frontend/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!frontend/).*)$ frontend/$1 [L]
```